I want to start node.js/express server but have error 'module not found'
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
console.log('Server listens to port')
 })

Trying to run on port and have this error, had this error many times and don't get why, if someone can tell me please.
$ pnpm start

backend@1.0.0 start C:\Users\user\Desktop\Chat-app\backend
node ./server.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Chat- 
app\backend\server.js'
at Module._resolveFilename 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
  (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.15.1



Why did you add the C++ language tag?

Also please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text as text into your questions.

server.js does not exist in the directory from which you are running the command node ./server.js. The error message is self explanatory.

Yes does not exist but every time have this bug when want to start server, working in  vscode.

It was my mistake about c++.

What is your cwd and what files are in this folder? How do you try to start the app via cli or some fancy button in vscode? Add some details.

MODULE_NOT_FOUND is typical for file not found when starting node. Specifically, your pnpm start script is looking for server.js in the location of C:\Users\user\Desktop\Chat-app\backend.
VScode usually opens the integrated terminal in a root workspace directory.

Check the current working directory in integrated terminal by entering the following in the terminal. (Mac/Linux: pwd Windows: cd)

Confirm that the server.js file is present in this command: (Mac/linux: ls Windows: dir)

You may need to adjust your working directory in VScode to ensure ./server.js is relative to the cwd in vscode. OR modify the pnpm start script to where ./server.js is located. Such as ./backend/server.js


I am not 100% on your setup so hopefully this is somewhat helpful.
